# Anime Inspired Games

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Can you legally create a game which is inspired off an anime? If so, can you use concepts / ideas but labelled under something else without issue?

Comment: You can't *ensure* that there are no legal consequences. People can always try to sue you for any reason whatsoever. The question is how likely you are to win the lawsuit and what it would cost you to win it.

Comment: There are some questions on game development stackexchange which might be useful to you: [How closely can a game legally resemble another?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another) | [Legal issues for a “fangame” of a commercial franchise?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/712/legal-issues-for-a-fangame-of-a-commercial-franchise/715#715)